# MVC 3 - Writing to productive Database on SQL Server 2005 does not work (testing on local SQL Server 2008 does work)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, connection-string

I'm a bit confused. I built my MVC 3 project which works fine in my development environment and the integrated IIS in Visual Studio 2010.

After deploying it to an IIS 7 it seemed to work, too. Reading does. But when I try to change some database values, it simply does not do anything. It seems to work, but after a reload of the changed values, they aren't changed at all.

Development database is on a local MS SQL Server 2008 and production on a remote Server with SQL Server 2005 (in this case, but the version will differ later on). Is there any difference? The user in the connection string has full rights, since changing works via Management Studio.

The connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="MyDBEntities"
  connectionString="metadata=
                    res://*/Models.MyDB.csdl|
                    res://*/Models.MyDB.ssdl|
                    res://*/Models.MyDB.msl;
                    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                    provider connection string=&quot;
                    data source=10.90.0.88;
                    initial catalog=MyDB;
                    persist security info=True;
                    user id=foo;
                    password=bar;
                    multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                    App=EntityFramework&quot;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: I build the project with Entity Framework 4.1 which is installed on the server. Well, reading does work though...

Comment: These types of problems are often the result of pointing to the wrong DB instance. Try checking all of your connection assignments.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ensuring that you have the correct connection details. The easiest way I can think of would be :

1. Create a new text file ( f.e. connection.txt )
2. Rename '.txt' to '.udl'
3. Double-click the created connection.udl file
4. Provide all the required connection details, hit 'Test connection' button
5. If it works, hit 'OK' button, open the file with Notepad - connection string will be inside of your connection.udl file. If it doesn't work - you need to find out proper server details ( check instance name, port number, if your user has the correct permissions )

Comment: Testing the connection works fine. I get something like `Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Password=bar;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=foo;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Data Source=10.90.0.88` which seems to be somehow the same as before. The thing is, that i can read the db, but not write to it.

Comment: are you sure your user has privileges to write on the particular database you're testing ? what kind of an error you get when you try to update your db ?

Comment: There is no error when updating for example a "customer". It just doesn't save the data. And the user has got rights to change anything in that database. The credentials work with the SQL Management Studio. On an SQL Server 2008 everything works. On 2005: no writing.

Comment: use the credentials to login to sql 2005 instance in production and then actually issue DML to insert data.